# Stopping event from happening twice in a row

Tags: jquery, html, events

I'm trying to create a dynamic one page website. I'm trying to work with jQuery to hide and show different divs when clicking on the menu items. I'm trying to prevent the fade effect from happening again when you press the menu button belonging to the page you're already on, but I can't seem to figure out how I do this.

```
<nav>             
    <ul>
        <li><a id="main" href="#" class="selected">My Work</a></li>
        <li><a id="about" href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>           
    </ul> 
</nav><!-- end navigation menu -->

<section class="main content"> </section>          
<section class="about content"> </section> <!-- End about -->
<section class="contact content">  </section> <!-- End contact -->
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("nav ul li a").click(function(){
        var cls = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".content").fadeOut(100);
        $('.' + cls).delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        return false;
    });

});
```

I'm not that good at jQuery. I'm also figuring out how to change the selected tab when I click the right link.

Answer (score 0):

using callback and preventDefault in jquery

```
$("nav ul li a").click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var cls = $(this).attr('id');

        $(".content").fadeOut(100, function() { 
            $('.' + cls).fadeIn(100);
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("nav ul li a").click(function(){
    if( !$(this).hasClass('selected'){
        var cls = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".content").fadeOut(100);
        $('.' + cls).delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        return false;
    };
});

});
```

Adding the 'if' statement around the action will prevent the event firing off when your 'a' has a class of 'selected' - ie. you're already on that page/section.

Comment: or just change the selector `$("nav ul li a:not(.selected)")`